# list indices must be integers or slices, not str Django

Tags: python, django

I m getting this error. I am new in django. I am trying so send mail with django.

**Tracke Back :**

```
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bari/Desktop/email_send/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bari/Desktop/email_send/Simple_Email_Send_Project/email_app/views.py", line 36, in send_mail
    message_body = form.changed_data["message_body"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
[05/Jun/2020 17:55:22] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 69463
```

my `views.py`

```
def send_mail(request):

    form = SendMailForm(request.POST)
    template = 'send_mail.html'
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data["subject"]
        message_body = form.changed_data["message_body"]
        email_address = form.cleaned_data["email_address"]

    try:
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email_address])
        mail.send()
        return render(request, template,
                      {'email_form': form, 'error_message': 'Sent mail to {}'.format(email_address)})

    except:
        return render(request, template,
                      {'email_form': form, 'error_message': 'Email Send failed. Please try again later'})
```

**How can I solve this ???** help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: your `form.changed_data` is returning a list, not a dictionary which you are expecting

Comment: Oh I got it .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Django documentation at [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data)

form.changed_data returns the name of fields in the models where the data has changed provided that the initial form. As you don't have any initial parameters in your code I think it's a **typo** at.

```py
message_body = form.cleaned_data["message_body"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using single quotes rather that double quotes.I think it saying slices means it wants characters rather that a string.

This worked for me i don't know why either im also new to django

so like this:

```
message_body = form.cleaned_data['message_body']
                                 ^            ^
```